# how to change "noopener nofollow external noreferrer" to "dofollow" / Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to give a `dofollow` link on my wordpress blog, which leads the readers to another page.

For this I have tried to simply deposit the link normally. This did not work.

In the frontend it looked like this: `rel="noopener nofollow external noreferrer"`.

Then I tried a `dofollow` link with the attribute `rel="dofollow"`.
In the frontend it looked like this: `rel="dofollow noopener nofollow external noreferrer"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security measure when `target="_blank"` is used (external linking). Natively as soon as you remove `target="_blank"` the default behaviour is to "follow".

> Strictly speaking, a `dofollow` link isn’t a thing. `dofollow` is simply the default state for a link. Said another way, any link without the `nofollow` attribute is a `dofollow` link.

- Source @ https://blog.alexa.com/dofollow-vs-nofollow-links/

You can refer to @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types for more informations regarding link types.

[image]

Are you using Gutenberg? you should be able to control some behaviour straight from the publishing section. If you disable `Open in a new tab` it should remove any link type restrictions.